# Calculating number of hours spent per product, with diminishing effort

Tags: excel, math

I want to calculate the number of work hours it takes to produce X. The first X takes 20 hours, but for each X it takes 20% less time. However, it will always take a minimum of 2 hours.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a maths problem, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried f(x)=1+(x^.8) but I'm not sure that represents what I'm trying to do. The curve looks similar to what I want though.

Comment: What minimum are you talking about? For infinite number of steps time becomes zero. I would be nice to look at simple example

Comment: The work to produce X will never be below 2 hours, no matter how efficient.

Comment: I've started answering the question assuming you want the total time to produce n items, but I'm not sure if that's what you want - maybe you only want the time to produce the nth item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, this is really easy: 20% less means you are calculating 80% of the value, which in fact means that you are multiplying the value with 0.8.
As the value can't go below 2, you can simply take the maximum between the calculated value and 2, using the formula:

```
=MAX(2,0.8*A1)
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Have fun!

In order to calculate the sum, you can use the simple formula `=SUM(A$1:A2)` up to the end, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is great and it does what I wanted to do! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An individual term of a geometric series is given by

[image]

The sum of a geometric series is given by

[image]

where in your case a=20 and r=0.8

You can show by taking logs or by trial and error that in your particular case you have

0.8^10 = 0.107374

so when n=11 you can see that the time has diminished to just over 2 hours. After that each rep takes 2 hours. So you have

```
=a*(1-r_^MIN(C2,11))/(1-r_)+MAX(0,C2-11)*2
```

for the total.

If you just want the time per item, it's

```
=IF(C2<=11,a*r_^(C2-1),2)
```

where a and r_ are named ranges for a and r, and the values of N are in column C.

[image]

Comment: Although your answer is right, why don't you let Excel do the calculation for you (as I did in my answer)? :-)

Comment: I added the sum too :-)

Comment: TBH I read the question as wanting the sum of the terms so I thought I might as well go for the sum of GP formula straight away as it's fairly straightforward. It does have the advantage of not needing a helper column and I suppose you could convert it to a spill formula if you had Excel 365 although that starts to be a bit ugly because Max and Min don't work =a*(1-r_^IF(C2:C15<=11,C2:C15,11))/(1-r_)+IF(C2:C15>11,C2:C15-11,0)*2 . Otherwise, I agree with you - the simplest way is usually the best.